# Change @domain ending when searching against AD

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-ldap

Domain

```
DC=red,DC=xyz
```

`userPrincipalName: firstname.lastname@blue.com` in AD

```
@Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider ap =
                new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domain, url);

        ap.setSearchFilter("(userPrincipalName={0})"); //change @ ending here?
        ap.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        ap.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        ap.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper);

        return ap;
    }
```

This code authenticates against AD successfully and tries to search the tree `DC=red,DC=xyz` using `userPrincipalName: firstname@red.xyz`

Search fails since @red.xyz is obsolete and @blue.com is used. How can I reconfigure the @ ending in java without changing domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that userPrincipalName was different than AD username and domain end. ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adds search parameter username@domain by default.

As a solution I overrided ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider and changed the search filter to sAMAccountName and value to plain username without domain.